# makefile: find a position of word in a variable

Tags: makefile

In my makefile, I need to make a variable assignment based on a command line variable value. for example, I do:

```
make var_1=xxx
```

where `var_1` can have one of say 100 possible values. Based on the value of `var_1`, I need to assign a value to `var_2` in my makefile. I could do:

```
ifeq ($(var_1), a)
   var_2 = A
endif
ifeq ($(var_1), b)
   var_2 = B
endif
```

and so on for all 100 possible combinations of `var_1`, `var_2`. Here `a`,`A`,`b`,`B` represent some strings. How do I do this to avoid 100's of `if` statements? I was thinking to define two variables:

```
var_1_values = a b c d     
var_2_values = A B C D
```

I can use `$(findstring $(var_1),$(var_1_values))` to see if `$(var_1)` is among `$(var_1_values)`, but how do I locate the position of `$(var_1)` among all `$(var_1_values)`? That position is then to be used to pick the corresponding word inside `$(var_2_values)`.

Comment: Doh!  I goofed.  Deleted my completely wrong-headed answer.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: cool, glad you have a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little kludgey, but if there's a symbol you know won't be in any of the values (such as "_") you could do this:

```
var_1_values = a b c d
var_2_values = A B C D

# This will be a_A b_B c_C d_D
LIST1 = $(join $(addsuffix _,$(var_1_values)),$(var_2_values))

var_1 := a

# The filter gives a_A, the subst turns it into A
var_2 = $(subst $(var_1)_,,$(filter $(var_1)_%, $(LIST1)))
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done quite slickly using recursion inside GNU make functions as follows:

```
_pos = $(if $(findstring $1,$2),$(call _pos,$1,\
       $(wordlist 2,$(words $2),$2),x $3),$3)
pos = $(words $(call _pos,$1,$2))
```

To use it you would `$(call)` the `pos` function with two arguments: the item to find and the list to find it in. For example,

```
$(call pos,a,a b c d e f g)
$(call pos,e,a b c d e f g)
$(call pos,g,a b c d e f g)
$(call pos,h,a b c d e f g)
$(call pos,e,))
```

It works by recursing through the `$2` argument until it can no longer find the value in `$1`. Each time it recurses it lops the head off `$2` using `$(wordlist 2,$(words $2),$2)`. Each time is recurses it adds an `x` to the returned string so that there is one `x` for each position through `$2` up to where `$1` was found.

It then just uses `$(words)` to count the length of the return from `_pos` (the number of `x`s).

If you use the GMSL project this can be written more slickly write this as:

```
_pos = $(if $(findstring $1,$2),$(call $0,$1,$(call rest,$2),x $3),$3)
pos = $(words $(call _$0,$1,$2))
```

Note that I used `$0` here which will contain the name of the current function (that's a standard GNU make feature) and the GMSL function `rest` to lop the head off the list.

Answer (score 5):

There's a smooth way to do this using recursion as follows. First define a function called `pos` that finds the position of an element in a list and then use `$(word)` to extract the corresponding element in another list.

Here's `pos`:

```
_pos = $(if $(findstring $1,$2),$(call _pos,$1,\
       $(wordlist 2,$(words $2),$2),x $3),$3)
pos = $(words $(call _pos,$1,$2))
```

Read this answer to understand how it works: [Makefile: find function which returns position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468683/makefile-find-function-which-returns-position/37483527#37483527)

Now it's easy to define a function that finds an element in a list and the finds the corresponding element in another list.

```
lookup = $(word $(call pos,$1,$2),$3)
```

And then try if out like this:

```
ALPHA := a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
NATO := alpha beta charlie delta echo foxtrot gamma hotel india\
        juliet kilo lima mike november oscar papa quebec romeo\
        sierra tango uniform victor whisky yankee zulu
to-nato = $(call lookup,$1,$(ALPHA),$(NATO))
```

To make a `to-nato` function that converts from a letter of the alphabet to the NATO alphabet.

Answer (score 4):

One way simulate associative containers in make is to use [computed variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Computed-Names). E.g.:

```
var_2.a := A
var_2.b := B
# ...

# lookup
var_2 = ${var_2.${var_1}}
# or, lookup and assign a default value if lookup fails
var_2_or_default = $(or ${var_2.${var_1}},<default-value>)
```

Comment: That looks like a struct data structure, but it's all text manipulation. Really nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
FAB = macrofab
# NOTE: base starts at 1 instead of 0
none := 1
seeed := 1
oshpark := 2
macrofab := 2
pcbng := 3
#NOTE: String must end with a space for word function to work
SUFFIX_DRILLS := "txt xln drl "

.PHONY: gerber

gerber:
    @echo $(FAB) drill suffix is $(word $($(FAB)), $(SUFFIX_DRILLS))
```

---

Output of make is:
macrofab drill suffix is xln

Answer (score 0):

This works in mingw gnu make 4.3 :

```
define get_index
$(shell \
    $(eval _c = 1)\
    $(eval _b = n n) \
    $(foreach x,$(2), \
        $(eval _b += n \
        $(eval _c = $(words $(_b)) \
        $(if $(filter $(1),$(x)), \
            $(eval _r = $(_c)))))) \
            echo $(_r) \
    $(eval _c =) \
    $(eval _b =) \
    $(eval _r =) \
)
endef
```

Takes two arguments; the word to search for and the list where to search.
The index is 'returned' by echoing in $(shell ...)

Example:

```
list = cow horse chicken
index = $(call get_index,horse,$(list))
@echo $(index)

# output: 2
```

Comment: I think the variable assignment makes this function problematic for parallel make runs. The `make` library [gmtt has a index-of function](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-index-ofwordlist).