# Makefile: find function which returns position

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to have a function in my Makefile which behaves as following:

```
$(find s, text)
```

Returns the position of the s in text. For example:

```
$(find c, a b c d)
3
```

Basically i search for the opposite of `word`:

```
$(word $(find c, a b c d), alpha beta gamma delta) => gamma
```

Otherwise, how can i make a connection between two argument lists?
I am using explicit rules. I want to find out which one was matched, by position in order to get the string i want. `$N` should be the position in the explicit rule. Here is an example:

```
OBJ = a.o b.o
OTHERS = something somewhat

all: b.o
OBJ:
    @echo $(word $N, $(OTHERS)) $@
```

This would produce `somewhat`.

Comment: never mind, it was a duplicate. I found the answer.