# Extract pattern and word following it from a Makefile variable

Tags: filter, makefile

I have a Makefile question and I can’t seem to figure this out.

I have the following variable in my Makefile

```
AA := word1 word2 word3 word4 word5

AAA = $(patsubst word2% $(word 1, %), word22, $(AA))
```

What I want AAA to be is

```
AAA := word1 word22 word4 word5
```

I want to search for a known pattern word2 and the unknown word following it and replace it with word22. Unfortunately I don’t know word3 before hand all I know is I need to replace word2 and the next word following it. Is there a clever way to do this?. I thought of using $filter and $filter-out Makefile functions but don't know how to extract the pattern and the word(s) following it.

I would also like a variation where I would replace word2 with word22 and insert word33 after the word following word2. So AAA would look like:

```
AAA := word1 word22 word3 word33 word4 word5
```

Thanks for your help. I was trying to do this without invoking shell and sed

Comment: Replacing a matched word is simple enough using gmake internal features, but more difficult to drop the next word, and further difficult without a shell or sed. Stuff like a word index and some math would work.  There's a partial solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483527/10304821)

Comment: Can you clarify what is the actual problem you are trying to solve ?. May be there is a better approach.

Comment: Based on a command line switch to make I am switching compilers so the arguments passed to compiler 1 will need to be altered for compiler 2. The Makefile is written with the default compiler1 and when compiler2 is chosen on the command line cerain arguments will need to be changed so I am trying to modify the arguments for compiler 1 for compiler2.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in functions of `make` do not allow for complex string process. In particular, the patterns are limited using '%' as wildcard. Given this limitations, few choices:

- Use external program (sed, etc) to perform the translation
- Use the built-in `guile` (if compiled into make).
- Complex: use foreach to find the match, the and remove the following word. Unfortunately, this very challenging as make does not ahve any arithmetic/logic.

The simplest approach is to use external program (sed, awk, perl) to perform translation. Solution using 'sed'

```
AA := word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
P := word2

AAA = $(shell echo ${AA} | sed -e 's/$P  *[^ ]*/word22/')

t:
    echo "AAA=${AAA}"
```

The output is: `AAA=word1 word22 word4 word5`

Answer (score 0):

For make-only solution, consider the following, which is using `foreach` to perform the substitution/token removal as needed

```
AA := word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
P := word2
R := word22

PREV=
# Loop with X over items
#   Replace P with R
#   Ignore word following P
#   Set PREV=$X
DDD := $(foreach X, ${AA}, $(if $(findstring $X,$P),$R,$(if $(findstring $(PREV),$P),,$X)) $(eval PREV=$X))

x:
        echo 'C=${DDD}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I take your comment

> Based on a command line switch to make I am switching compilers so the arguments passed to compiler 1 will need to be altered for compiler 2.

as the true problem you want to solve. You can try to solve it with ad-hoc programming, either in `make` or with the help of command line tools like `sed`. The former has the problem of being quite hard to comprehend after some time or with the code in the hands of a different programmer, the latter can be equally involved and needs those tools installed. The third option is to use [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which is a `GNUmake` library written for such build configuration tasks:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
# Define a table which selects the executable depending on cmd-line parameter 1
define COMPILER_EXECUTABLE
2
foo   gcc
bar   clang
baz   arm-none-eabi-gcc
endef

# Additional command line args depending on compiler
define ADDITIONAL_CFLAGS
2
gcc                 -E
gcc                 -O2
clang               -DUSE_CLANG
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m7
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mthumb
endef

# Select column 2 from COMPILER_EXECUTABLE where cmd-line parameter 1 == first column
CC := $(call select,2,$(COMPILER_EXECUTABLE),$$(call str-eq,$(CMD_LINE_PARAM_1),$$1))

# Fetch additional CFLAGS
CFLAGS += $(call select,2,$(ADDITIONAL_CFLAGS),$$(call str-eq,$(CC),$$1))

$(info compiler: $(CC))
$(info CFLAGS: $(CFLAGS))
```

Testing it:

```
make CMD_LINE_PARAM_1=foo
```

Output:

```
compiler: gcc
CFLAGS: -E -O2
```

The rationale is to simply save the time for your first attempt - if you lay down your information in tabular format, nothing is lost if you later want to switch to a build method better fitting your software process. The interface to the `select` (and most other gmtt functions) aren't particularly complicated, neither to comprehend nor to replicate in another language.

Comment: dash-o and Vroomfondel thanks for your comments and solutions. I will try them out and I am sure I can settle on one of these.